# Multiple instances of a component causing event handling issues

Tags: reactjs, event-handling

I was creating a text editor component for my react project from scratch. It is working fine alone but when I add another instance on the same page some of the or sometimes all of the functional keys stop working. Also, sometimes when I click the insetImage or createLink icon to insert link or image the prompt appears as many times as there are instances of that component. I don't know what's happening. I tried to get solution from various sources, I even tried gpt but the problem still persists. I think when i click on any of the functional keys, event handlers for all the instances gets called one by one (as per my thinking). Here is the component's code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ulIcon from "../../assets/svgs/list-ul-alt_svgrepo.com.svg";
import olIcon from "../../assets/svgs/list-ol_svgrepo.com.svg";
import attachMent from "../../assets/svgs/attachment-right-svgrepo-com.svg";
import negativeIcon from "../../assets/svgs/negative sign.svg";
import subscriptIcon from "../../assets/svgs/subscript-svgrepo-com.svg";
import superscriptIcon from "../../assets/svgs/superscript-svgrepo-com.svg";

export default function TextEditor() {
  const [editorText, setEditorText] = useState("Enter question here...");

  function handleChange(e) {
    setEditorText(e.target.value);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleFunctionalKeyClick = (event) => {
      console.log("triggered");
      const func = event.target.getAttribute("data-func");
      if (func) {
        if (func == "insertImage") {
          const url = prompt("Enter url here", "http://");
          if (url !== null) {
            document.execCommand(func, false, url);
          }
        } else {
          document.execCommand(func, false);
        }
      }
    };
    const functionalKeysContainer = document.querySelectorAll("[data-func]");
    const nodeList = Array.from(functionalKeysContainer);
    nodeList.forEach((node) => {
      node.addEventListener("click", handleFunctionalKeyClick);
    });

    return () => {
      nodeList.forEach((node) => {
        node.removeEventListener("click", handleFunctionalKeyClick);
      });
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center items-center flex-col w-full h-dvh">
      <div className="EditorContainer flex-col flex gap-2 relative w-fit">
        <div className="border-2 border-black rounded-xl p-2">
          <div
            className="w-[45rem] max-w-full h-fit max-h-20 overflow-y-scroll text-3xl outline-none"
            id="editor"
            contentEditable
            onChange={handleChange}
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: editorText }}
          />
        </div>
        <div
          id="functionalKeys"
          className="functions bg-white flex gap-1 items-center border-2 border-black rounded-md w-fit p-1  right-2 bottom-[0.5rem] m-auto select-none"
        >
          <div className="bold" title="Bold" data-func="bold">
            B
          </div>
          <div className="pipe">|</div>
          <div className="italic" title="Italic" data-func="italic">
            I
          </div>
          <div className="pipe">|</div>
          <div className="underline" title="Underline" data-func="underline">
            U
          </div>
          <div className="pipe">|</div>
          <div
            className="unorderedList otherFunctionalIcons"
            title="unordered-list-icon"
          >
            <img
              src={ulIcon}
              alt="attachment icon"
              className="p-2 w-full cursor-pointer"
              title="unordered-list-icon"
              data-func="insertUnorderedList"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="pipe">|</div>
          <div
            className="attachment otherFunctionalIcons"
            title="ordered-list-icon"
          >
            <img
              src={olIcon}
              alt="attachment icon"
              className="p-2 w-full cursor-pointer"
              title="ordered-list-icon"
              data-func="insertOrderedList"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="pipe">|</div>
          <div className="attachment otherFunctionalIcons" title="subscript">
            <img
              src={subscriptIcon}
              alt="attachment icon"
              className="p-2 w-full cursor-pointer"
              title="subscript"
              data-func="subscript"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="pipe">|</div>
          <div className="attachment otherFunctionalIcons" title="superscript">
            <img
              src={superscriptIcon}
              alt="superscript icon"
              className="p-2 w-full cursor-pointer"
              title="superscript"
              data-func="superscript"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="pipe">|</div>
          <div className="attachment otherFunctionalIcons" title="Add image">
            <img
              src={attachMent}
              alt="attachment icon"
              className="p-2 w-full cursor-pointer"
              title="Add image"
              data-func="insertImage"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="pipe">|</div>
          <div
            className="removeDecoration p-2 active:bg-[var(--black25)] rounded-lg cursor-pointer"
            title="Remove all Decorations"
          >
            <img
              src={negativeIcon}
              alt=""
              className="h-6"
              title="Remove all Decorations"
              data-func="removeFormat"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

for now, I'm not getting what to do next? I asked GPT but none of the solutions worked out.

Answer (score 0):

You bind event listeners to all DOM element with a `[data-func]` attribute using this line:

```
const functionalKeysContainer = document.querySelectorAll("[data-func]");
```

So each `TextEditor` component attaches to event listeners to all the DOM elements of previously mounted `TextEditor` components. When you click a element with multiple handlers, all of them are fired at once.

### Solution 1 - use React events system and not the DOM's

Attach an event listener to each button manually (or render them in a loop). Remove the `useEffect` block, extract the `handleFunctionalKeyClick` function, and change it to accept a `func` string, instead of an event object:

```
const handleFunctionalKeyClick = func => {
  if (func == "insertImage") {
    const url = prompt("Enter url here", "http://");
    if (url !== null) {
      document.execCommand(func, false, url);
    }
  } else {
    document.execCommand(func, false);
  }
};
```

**Note**: you can also split it into multiple function to address specific applications, for example handle "insertImage".

Now add an `onClick` attribute to the each element, and pass the `func` string  instead of of using a `data-func` attribute:

```
<img
  onClick={() => handleFunctionalKeyClick('insertUnorderedList')}
  src={ulIcon}
  alt="attachment icon"
  className="p-2 w-full cursor-pointer"
  title="unordered-list-icon"
/>
```

### Solution 2 - add unique DOM `id` to each editor

If you must attach event handlers via the DOM, you can generate a unique `id` for each component using the [`useId` hook](https://react.dev/reference/react/useId).

```
export default function TextEditor() {
  const id = useId();
  const [editorText, setEditorText] = useState("Enter question here...");
```

Use the `id` instead of the static "functionalKeys" id:

```
<div
  id={id}
  className="functions bg-white flex gap-1 items-center border-2 border-black rounded-md w-fit p-1  right-2 bottom-[0.5rem] m-auto select-none"
>
```

When attaching the event handlers in the `useEffect` use the `id` to select elements with the "[data-func]" attribute that only exist in that specific component:

```
const functionalKeysContainer = document.querySelectorAll(`#${id} [data-func]`);
```